# as a direction to

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> signature
>
> 3a : a letter or figure placed usually at the bottom of the first page on each sheet of printed pages (as of a book) as a **direction** to the binder in arranging and gathering the sheets

Source: 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signature

> signature
>
> 8
> a. a printed sheet folded to page size for binding together, with other such sheets, to form a book, magazine, etc.
>
> b. a mark placed on the first page of every sheet to guide the binder in folding and gathering them.

Source: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/signature

---

I think that "**direction**" means "guide", not "instruction".
However, the "direction" entry in any dictionaries doesn't include a sense of "guide".

What do you think about that?

Comment: What do you think the difference is between *guide* and *instruction* here?

Comment: @stangdon I think that "instruction" means "the written information that tells you how to do or use something" and that "guide" means "something that helps to direct a person's actions, thoughts, etc.". I think that they have different meanings.

Comment: The signatures in a printed book are indeed instructions to the binder, who cannot choose to bind them in a different order.

Comment: 'Directions' used in this sense are instructions. If your boss directs you to do something, you have to do it, or get in trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean. [M-W's first entry for "direction"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/direction) does in fact "include a sense of 'guide'". (The very first word is "guidance".) Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direction is literally *that which directs*. The first meaning of the word in in the Merriam-Webster dictionary is "**guidance** or supervision of action or conduct". A guide provides guidance. They're the same concept.

Direction can be detailed instructions or a simple marker that somebody who knows what they're doing will understand.